# Flask is not recognizing my form from HTML

Tags: python, html, flask, frontend

I'm working on an upload file function for my web tool and I'm facing an issue. The problem is that Flask is not receiving the files from the HTML form. I have already set the route, and created the form tag accordingly to what is required like the method POST and still not working. Am I doing anything wrong?

**HTML**

```html
<form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="row form-group">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
         <div class="control-group" id="fields">
            <label class="control-label" for="field1">
               Requests
            </label>
            <div class="controls">
               <div class="entry input-group upload-input-group">
                  <input class="form-control" name="fields[]" type="file">
                  <button class="btn btn-upload btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                     <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                  </button>
               </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Upload</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

**Python/Flask**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app=Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = "secret key"
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024

path = os.getcwd()
# file Upload
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(path, 'uploads')

if not os.path.isdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER):
    os.mkdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['xlsx', 'xls'])


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No file selected for uploading')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            flash('File successfully uploaded')
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            flash('Allowed file types are xlsx and xls')
            return redirect(request.url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host = '127.0.0.1',port = 5000, debug = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the input name to `file` instead `fields[]`

`<input class="form-control" name="file" type="file">`

Comment: It worked, but Flask is only receiving one file. How can I do to make it two? Thanks!